# How to check for a range of numbers in matlab

Tags: matlab, if-statement, numbers, switch-statement, range

I am writing a matlab code for a problem and I am using a switch case to check for a series of numbers. Using a switch case is a requirement of the assignment.

```
switch score    
case {90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100}    
  disp('Your grade is an A');   
case {80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89}
  disp('Your grade is an B');
case {70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79}
  disp('Your grade is an C');
case {60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69}
 disp('Your grade is an D');
otherwise
 disp('Your grade is an F');
end
```

Is there anyway to make the range easier to type like `score < 60` etc.?

How to check for decimals if this original way is the only way?

Answer (score 3):

If you know you always keep scoring like this, you can use

```
switch floor(score/10)
case {9 10}
case 8
case 7
[...]
end
```

However, if you think that the scoring function might change, it is useful to convert score to class index before you call the `switch` statement.

For example

```
%# calculate score index
nextClass = [60 70 80 90];
scoreIdx = sum(score>=nextClass);

%# assign output
switch scoreIdx
case 5
%# A
case 4
%# B
[...]

end
```

Of course, you could replace the switch command entirely with the `scoreIdx` variable above.

```
grades = 'FDCBA';
fprintf('Your grade is an %s',grades(scoreIdx+1))
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, I'll give it a try and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use num2cell together with `:`

```
case num2cell(60:69)
```

in your case, you will have:

```
 switch score 

case num2cell(90:100)

 disp('Your grade is an A');

 case num2cell(80:89)

 disp('Your grade is an B');

 case num2cell(70:79)

 disp('Your grade is an C');

 case num2cell(60:69)

 disp('Your grade is an D');

otherwise

 disp('Your grade is an F');

end
```

But given your problem, I think if-elseif-elseif-else with number comparison `>` and `<` is more appropriate, since there could be half marks. Right now using your switch statement, 99.5 would get and 'F'.

`

Comment: Thanks for your response, but unfortunatly I can't use else-if and have to use the swtich statement, any ideas on what I can do? thanks

Comment: Then just do the num2cell(60:69) as I wrote above.

Answer (score 0):

I think writing an if statement would make the code a bit easier. With this, you dont need to explicitly test each case, just have the first "event" that triggers set the grade:

```
score = 75;

if score >= 90
    disp('Your grade is an A');
elseif score >= 80
    disp('Your grade is an B');
elseif score >= 70
    disp('Your grade is an C');
elseif score >= 60
    disp('Your grade is an D');
else
    disp('Your grade is an F');
end
```

Output:

```
Your grade is an C
```

Comment: It would be nice if I was allowed to use the else if statements, but one of the requirments is that it must be a switch